# How do we set a datepicker default value to 1 year from today?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, datepicker

How do we set to an angular mat date picker where the default selected value is 1 year from today ?. Thanks.

When the date picket loads the default value should be 1 year from now.

[image]

#html code

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="full-width"  [ngClass]="{'date-field-error-underline': walgreensFields.formError.nextNoticeEndDate !== null}">
                <mat-label [ngClass]="{'c-error':walgreensFields.formError.nextNoticeEndDate !== null}">Expiration Date Range (End)</mat-label>
                  <input 
                  matInput 
                  hidden
                  (dateChange)="setNextNoticeEndDate($event)" 
                  [(ngModel)]="walgreensFields.nextNoticeEndDate"
                  [matDatepicker]="endDatePicker"
                  >
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="endDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #endDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
                <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper date-field-custom-error" *ngIf="walgreensFields.formError.nextNoticeEndDate !== null">
                  <div class="mat-error">{{walgreensFields.formError.nextNoticeEndDate}}</div>                        
                </div>
             </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default value of your `walgreensFields.nextNoticeEndDate` that is binded to the datepicker using `[(ngModel)]` to one year from today's date. To do this you could use `Date#setFullYear` to set the year to one more than current `Date#getFullYear`:

```js
  exampleDate = new Date();

  ngOnInit(): void {
     walgreensFields.nextNoticeEndDate = this.exampleDate.setFullYear(this.exampleDate.getFullYear() + 1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Three ways:

1. Set the [value] property on the input, in this stackblitz I have it set for today's date. (https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-datepicker-work-naxbzw?file=src/app/datepicker-overview-example.html)
2. If using a form, then set the specific formControl to have your desired default date.
3. Using your ngModel

   ngOnInit(): void {
   walgreensFields.nextNoticeEndDate = this.exampleDate.setFullYear(this.exampleDate.getFullYear() + 1);
   }

Comment: but what If I wanna set the default value of the date picker ? do you have some example with that Sir?

Comment: The two possible options above would do that, you can also try the answer Troudi posted as that would set the value of your model to be set to, in his example, today's date last year (2/3/2021). A datepicker is just an input with fancy styling and event listeners associated with it

Answer (score 0):

```
walgreensFields.nextNoticeEndDate= new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear()-1))
```

Comment: Hi , when we say 1 year from Today Sir , isnt that a future date right ? when I check and tried your code it displays  hu Feb 04 2021 03:27:41 .....

Comment: it should be February 4, 2023

Comment: Just change his -1 to +1